# how to get product price detail using zbarsdk barcode scanner

Tags: web-services

I am using ZbarSDK to get product detail by scanning product bar code, but i am only getting   bar code no which is with bar code,but i need product detail like product name,price etc.
Please help me with this issue.

Thanks

Comment: This is not an objective-c question at all (or even a question really).  Do a little research (maybe a google search for something like "get upc info web service").

Answer (score 2):

The ultimate result after scanning a barcode number.you have to then search this barcode for product details.
Try the following api to search product details

http://www.searchupc.com/handlers/upcsearch.ashx?request_type=3&access_token={my_token}&upc={scanned_code}

Comment: You have to register on the public product search site which is free
and the you get a free access token
the URL is 
http://www.searchupc.com/